# Thymeleaf Map<String, Object> iteration and non-english chars in map key

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I have Spring, Thymeleaf, HTML5 web page. And have problem iterating through Map if map object contains non-english characters.

1. All the character encoding filters/resolvers/converters are set and forced to UTF-8

Let's say I have the following setup:

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/app", method =  { RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST })
public String view(ModelMap model, @RequestParam(value = "foo", required = false) Integer foo) {
   MapDTO mapDto = new MapDTO();
   Map<String, List<Foo>> mapFoo ... // populate map etc.
   model.add("mapDto", mapDto.setMapFoo(mapFoo))
   return foo == null ? VIEW : VIEW + " :: fooFragment"
}
```

And template for testing purposes:

```
.. page ..
<div th:fragment="fooFragment" id="fooFragment">
  ..
  <th:block th:each="fooMap : ${mapDto.mapFoo}">
    <th:block th:each="item,row : ${fooMap.value.fooList}">
      <p th:text="${item.val}"</p> <!-- working OK -->
      <p th:text=" ${fooMap.value.fooList[__${row.index}__].idrValueName} "></p> <!-- working OK -->
      <input th:field="*{mapDto.mapFoo[__${fooMap.key}__].fooList[__${row.index}__].val} "></p><!-- And this is working -->
      <p th:text="${mapDto.mapFoo[__${fooMap.key}__].fooList[__${row.index}__].val} "></p><!-- FAILING ON THIS -->
    </th:block>
  </th:block>
  ..
</div>
.. rest of the page ..
```

Let's say, that i have map with keys "A" and "Ā".

2. I'm getting following exception:

`org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "mapDto.mapFoo[Ā].fooList[0].val"
..
Caused by: 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot handle (257) 'Ā'`

3. Whats interesting - I have almost exactly the same setup on different page (A bit different mapDto structure and template, but the same principle, same page headers) and I don't have the same issues there.
4. Maps that don't have keys with non-english characters behaves as predicted.

Any ideas where lies the problem?

SOLVED:
Solved described issue using double-bracket syntax
**${{...}}**
There are some limitations with it. But I was able to work around them it solved my main issue.

Comment: Instead of [solved] answer your question - [tour].

Answer (score 0):

`mapDto.mapFoo[Ā].fooList[0].val`

This expression contains accented character `Ā`. Looking at the source code of [Tokenizer](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.springsource.com/org.springframework/org.springframework.expression/3.1.0/org/springframework/expression/spel/standard/Tokenizer.java), accented characters are clearly indicated as an invalid candidate for tokenization.

Spring EL's [`InternalSpelExpressionParser`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring-expression/4.0.3.RELEASE/org/springframework/expression/spel/standard/InternalSpelExpressionParser.java) which is responsible for parsing expressions is tightly coupled to this `Tokenizer`, so I don't think there is an out of the box way to allow tokenization of accented characters. I'm pretty sure there is a good reason why this is not allowed (e.g. it might break other parts of the framework) so I suggest you go along to what the framework is demanding and remove the accented characters in the expression.